# install node-rdkafka on mac m1 pro chip

Tags: macos, npm, apple-m1, npm-package

I am trying to install `node-rdkafka` on my mac with m1 pro chip
using following command
`npm i node-rdkafka@2.15.0`  
it gives this error

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/aa/Project/D&A/temp/node_modules/node-rdkafka
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild`
```

I'm using *node v18.15.0*, I had enabled roseeta and changed arch to i386 instead of arm 64 with the help of `arch -x86_64 zsh`

I had tried reinstalling brew after converting the architecture, reinstalled node using nvm(which is picking x64 tar.gz file to download it), I had been using Python 3.11.4, openssl 1.1.1, any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: When you write that you used `arch -x86_64 zsh` it is clear you are just trying random things to solve your problem. Which is not unusual for this type of problem but neither is it likely to yield a solution. In general installation scripts tend to use the native architecture (e.g., `arm64`) even if run from a shell using a different architecture (e.g., `x86_64`). It is also not clear why you say "reinstalling brew" since I see nothing else in your question that suggests the Homebrew package manager is relevant.

Comment: hey @KurtisRader reinstalled it because previously i had installed it with arm64, when i get to know it can be changed to x86_64 so i thought of reinstalling it with it.

Comment: Installing Homebrew will always use the native (i.e., `arm64`) architecture on an Apple Silicon (aka "M1") system. If you read somewhere that "it can be changed to x86_64" you should stop reading that author/publisher since they have no idea what they are talking about. And your comment does not explain why you attempted to reinstall Homebrew using an x86_64 arch.

Comment: @KurtisRader as before changing to x86_64, it was arm64 and while installing node via it was picking the node version for arm64, and i had read it somewhere that to install node-rdkafka you need to install node as native or with x86_64, thats why i reinstalled it and after then when i installed node it was of x86_64, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Constructing native Node.js modules can prove complicated, particularly atop new architecture like Apple's M1 Pro chip. While the majority of modules operate smoothly with these new chips, some continue to struggle due to the absence of or incompatible dependencies. Let's try the following steps:

Ensure Xcode Command Line Tools are installed on your system:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Ensure you have installed the Python 2.7 version. Node-gyp requires Python 2.7 (not 3.x).
You can install it through Homebrew:

```
brew install python@2
```

And then, set it as the default within the node-gyp environment:

```
export PYTHON="/usr/local/bin/python2.7"
```

Install OpenSSL via Homebrew and link it correctly:

```
brew install openssl
```

Locate the OpenSSL path:

```
brew --prefix openssl
```

Export the OpenSSL path into your environment:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Finally, you need to ensure that Node.js itself is installed utilizing the correct architecture. You mentioned you've already attempted this with Rosetta 2 and nvm, but just to confirm, try running the installation in this manner:

```
arch -x86_64 zsh
nvm install v18.15.0
nvm use v18.15.0
npm i node-rdkafka@2.15.0
```

If all the above steps don't succeed, then there might be a problem with the node-rdkafka version itself and its compatibility with the M1 Pro chip.

Comment: Thanks @daniya, I had tried all the above steps(also tried changing node-rdkafka version) but it is still failing with the below error log file on below link
https://ufile.io/v8h8q9oq

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, 
daniya shyanne!

All eight of your answers here since you joined 3 days ago appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.